# What are the differences between DC Adventures and 3e M&M?

Tags: edition-comparison, mutants-and-masterminds-3e

DC Adventures is a version of 3e Mutants & Masterminds, released in advance of the core 3e books. In the course of answering someone's question on the Ronin Army forums about the legality of the Green Lantern build, I cited the different rule for Create, namely that ranged attacks were done as Ranged Damage with an allowable trade-off, versus standard 3e where they are treated as an Area Attack and thus are strictly PL capped.

That made me realize that I wasn't certain if I knew all of the differences between the two versions, aside from a different setting.

Comment: Apparently it's a common question online - here are 4 threads from the RPG.net forums asking the same thing: [#1](https://forum.rpg.net/index.php?threads/difference-between-3e-mutants-masterminds-and-dc-adventures.568416/), [#2](https://forum.rpg.net/index.php?threads/mutants-masterminds-3e-v-dc-adventures.642471/), [#3](https://forum.rpg.net/index.php?threads/what-are-the-differences-between-dc-adventures-and-m-m-3.667962/), [#4](https://forum.rpg.net/index.php?threads/question-about-m-m-3e-and-dc-adventures.685161/)

Comment: Ah, and it looks like everything but the Duration and Action modifications have been errataed.

Comment: I didn't really skim the linked threads, I just googled the issue and found them - if you think you've understood the answer to the question based on those, feel free to leave an answer! (Others can, of course, point out anything you've missed.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On initial release, there were three major mechanical differences between DCA and M&M 3E, and at least one minor one.

### Create

*Create* had a different mechanic for making a ranged attack, using a rolled attack instead of an area attack.

**DCA**

> Simply dropping an object on a target or targets requires
> a ranged attack check against Dodge. The object inflicts
> damage equal to its Toughness.

**M&M 3E**

> Simply dropping a created object on a target is treated like an Area Effect attack based on the object’s size (see Area extra). The object inflicts damage equal to its Toughness, and targets get a Dodge check to evade the falling object. A successful check results in no damage (rather than the usual half damage).

[This was fixed in the errata](https://freeronin.com/3e_files/DCAHHerrata.pdf) to match the 3E text (at the time, players noted that the original DCA version of *Create* gave all of the benefits of *Ranged Damage*, plus more, for the same cost).

### Increased Duration

DCA allowed three levels of Increased Duration.

- Instant to Concentration
- Concentration to Sustained
- Sustained to Continuous

M&M 3E reduced this to just the first and third items.

- Instant to Concentration
- Sustained to Continuous

### Growth / Shrinking

I've seen references to both *Growth* and *Shrinking* changing in their mechanics. The PDF I own of DCA has the same *Growth* description and cost as in M&M 3E (which also matches the errata entry). *Shrinking* has the same mechanics, but only costs 1 PP/rank (M&M 3E and the errata increase the cost to 2 PP/rank).

### Extra Effort - Resistance

The DCA Heroes Handbook states:

> Gain an immediate additional resistance check against an
> ongoing effect. If the extra effort incapacitates you, you
> forfeit all resistance checks against the effect until you recover. The fatigue conditions do not affect you until you
> are free of the effect.

The errata replaced this with the text seen in the 3E Heroes Handbook:

> Gain an immediate additional resistance check against an
> ongoing effect. If you’re compelled or controlled, the
> fatigue from the extra effort doesn't affect you until
> you’re free of the effect; this is so you can’t resist yourself
> to exhaustion as a way of avoiding being controlled!

Comment: Just a heads up, using code blocks for emphasis isn't a thing we do on this SE, though it is perfectly acceptable on a number of SEs. I switched it to *italics* in the edit.  [We have a meta on that](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3087/22566).

Comment: Ah. I was unaware.

Comment: Not a big deal, I didn't realize that until one of the old hands brought it to my attention.